# How to add (not append) a number to an existing value in a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

How could I do something like this without getting an error:

```
x,y = 0,0
x2,y2 = 1,1
lst = [(x,y), (x2,y2)]
lst[0][1] += 32
```

When I do that I get a TypeError, and the try method doesn't do what I want to do.

Comment: Tuples are inmutable, you could use a list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specify in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) on tuples:

> Tuples are immutable, and usually contain a heterogeneous sequence of
>   elements that are accessed via unpacking

So you could do the following:

**Approach 1: Create a new Tuple**

```
x, y = 0, 0
x2, y2 = 1, 1
lst = [(x, y), (x2, y2)]
lst[0] = (lst[0][0], lst[0][1] + 32)

print(lst)
```

**Output**

```
[(0, 32), (1, 1)]
```

**Approach 2: use list**

```
x, y = 0, 0
x2, y2 = 1, 1
lst = [[x, y], [x2, y2]]
lst[0][1] +=  32

print(lst)
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 32], [1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Tuples are immutable. As [@ Dani Mesejo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60946998/how-to-add-not-append-a-number-to-an-existing-value-in-a-tuple/60947104#comment107826880_60946998) suggests, you can use a list.

I suggest converting your list of tuples to a list of lists:

```
x,y = 0,0
x2,y2 = 1,1
lst = [(x,y), (x2,y2)]

# Do the conversion here. 
# Could just start out with a list of lists as well. 
lst = [list(x) for x in lst]

lst[0][1] += 32

print(lst)
# [[0, 32], [1, 1]]
```

Would make things easier just starting out with a list of lists:

```
lst = [[0,0], [1,1]]

lst[0][1] += 32

print(lst)
# [[0, 32], [1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuples, as Dani points out in his comment, are immutable.

You should create a new tuple and swap the tuple like this:

```
lst[0] = (lst[0][0], lst[0][1] + 32)
lst
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
x, y = 0, 0
x2, y2 = 1, 1
lst = [(x, y), (x2, y2)]
lst[0] = (lst[0][0], lst[0][1] + 32)

>> [(0, 32), (1, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

as per w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp

Once a tuple is created, you cannot change its values. Tuples are unchangeable, or immutable as it also is called.

But there is a workaround. You can convert the tuple into a list, change the list, and convert the list back into a tuple.

```
x = (1, 2, 3)
y = (4, 5, 6)

x1 = list(x)
y2 = list(y)
z = [x1, y2]
z[0][1] += 32
x = tuple(z[0])
y = tuple(z[1])

print(z) returns:
[[1, 32, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

print(x) returns:
(1, 34, 3)


print(y) returns:
(4, 5, 6)
```